# poi 5.0 generated xlsx file RUN TO EMAIL APPENDS .TXT TO OUTPUT

Tags: apache-poi

We are generating the Excel file in our organization using poi.After upgrading to poi 5.0 from poi 3.17,output RUN TO EMAIL APPENDS .TXT along with xlsx extension.That is instead of .xlsx result is appearing as .xlsx.txt.

The attachment was removed from this email message because it matched a
blocked file type extension

The same set up works fine with poi 3.17,with no changes in mail server and OS.

Could you please have a look.
Comment 1

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to generate this excel file

Comment: One strange observation I have is the xlsx file generated using poi 5.0 is shown as binary format while sharing.This is not the case with poi 3.17.I may be missing some dependency.But does anyone have any idea on this behaivour.Posted the query in POI site also,the working and non working files are attached there.Ref:https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66029

Comment: Both here and there you didn't post any code. Nobody can help you unless you share the code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.
Unfortunately I may not be able to post the code here ,its against the organisation policy.
My application code is same while working with POI 3.17 and POI 5.0.
But for xlsx file generated using POI 5.0 is in binary format while sharing(Please find the attachments shared).Just replacing the old poi binaries that is poi 3.17 in the same environment will make everything work.
Have we added any new functionality for encoding after poi 3.17 or anyone can point out any change that may lead to this.
Or if I am missing any dependency jars,please help me with that.

Comment: Check your error logs? Missing dependencies normally trigger a class or method not found exception. Otherwise if you won't share any code, you'll need to attach a debugger and step through the code yourself to see where it's going wrong / behaving differently...

Comment: "But for xlsx file generated using POI 5.0 is in binary format while sharing": All `*.xlsx` files are in `Office Open XML` format. This always is a binary format (a ZIP archive exactly). This has not changed from version 3.17 to version 5.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Alex.I have attached the working and non working xlsx in the poi bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66029 .If you try to share it over slack or something ,you can see the non working one showing binary format and the working one is still in xlsx.I have put the screenshot for this too there.